# How do I handle merge conflict - Git

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Consider the following scenario

There are two files

```
FileA
FileB
```

I have made changes to FileB. In the remote repository, Some one has made changes to the FileA and FileB. I pull in from the upstream and there is merge conflict in FileA.

I fix the merge conflict, now when I check `git status`, I see the FileA staged and FileB as modified.

`on branch master 
Your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit.
You have unmerged paths. (fix conflicts and run "git commit").
Changes to be committed:
modified: FileA
Unmerged paths: both modified FileB`

Here you can see status of FileA is in staged state on merge fail. But I didnt modify it. Now when I stage resolved conflict file FileB and commit, FileA will be there with the commit but the FileA is actually not touched by me.

It becomes so difficult when there are hundreds of files all appearing in the commit history on merge fail though it was not actually modified by me.

How can I deal with this situation in Git.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you are using eclipse but I often have to "Add to index" on the file that I resolved the conflict in.

Comment: @JaredSol So it wont appear in commit history again? I am using brackets.

Comment: If you committed before pulling then you will have a commit resolving the conflict. That's why it's always best to pull before committing. I'm not sure you can commit without it showing in the history. Although you probably could via command line somehow. I just haven't had the need.

Comment: @JaredSol - I believe git wont allow to pull from remote until everything is committed.

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

While resolving a merge conflict git will provide you with information to manually resolve the conflicts. In your case git informs you that remote master also contains a change in `FileA`, this may be helpfull if the changes in remote `FileB` depends on changes in `FileA`, a change that you may need to take in account when manually resolving the conflict in `FileB`.

You need to stage both `FileA` and `FileB` after you have resolved the conflict. If `FileA` is staged without any changes it will not be a part of the merge commit (the merge commit will not be included in the commit history for `FileA`)

**NOTE:** if you have a LF/CRLF conversion applied to your files they might contain whitespace changes when staged and therefor they will be included in the merge commit.

You might update you local repo by rebasing the changes onto your branch, but you may still need to keep track of any dependent changes introduced by this update.

Comment: Can I avoid this FileA coming up in the commit history?

Comment: You need to stage FileA when you have resolved the conflict, but if you have not done any changes to FileA while resolving the conflict it will not be a part of the merge commit. It sounds wierd to stage a file that will not be a part of the commit, but currently git needs to be explicitly informed about all files that is part of conflicted merge.

Comment: Exactly, I am staging FileA, but it is there is in the commit history along with the resolved files.

Comment: Can I overcome this using rebase or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Git does not manage files alone, but branches containing files, meaning you don't push changes on a file, you actually push your local branch state everytime.

In your case, if `FileA` was not included in your commit, then pushing your branch would override `FileA` on the remote with the one you had on your local branch, and the changes on `FileA` would be lost.

You can read more about branches on Git [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).